# What does `dword ptr` mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, dword, pointers

Could someone explain what this means? (Intel Syntax, x86, Windows)

```
and     dword ptr [ebp-4], 0
```

Comment: Note that the example here is almost never what you actually want.  To zero memory, use `mov dword ptr [ebp-4], 0`.  Using `and` saves 3 bytes of machine-code size, using an 8-bit immediate instead of 32-bit, at the cost of performance (load/AND/store for a memory destination AND instead of just a pure store.)

Comment: Related: [In assembly, what does \`PTR\` stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41562732) (with an equally short answer)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

The `dword ptr` part is called a size directive. [This page](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) explains them, but it wasn't possible to direct-link to the correct section.

Basically, it means "the size of the target operand is 32 bits", so this will bitwise-AND the 32-bit value at the address computed by taking the contents of the `ebp` register and subtracting four with 0.

Comment: The "d" in "dword" stands for "double".  A word is 16 bits.

Comment: For more reference visit this [link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/10/21/64-bit-types-and-arithmetic-on-32-bit-cpus/)

Comment: Why is the `PTR` part needed? Isn't dword enough to encode the size? NASM does not use `ptr` AFAIK.

Comment: @JeremyP Word mean is changing according to processors. After reading this article can you say again word is 16 bits or you are only defining the simple meaning of word which means two bytes?
`Modern processors, including embedded systems, usually have a word size of 8, 16, 24, 32, or 64 bits, while modern general purpose computers usually use 32 or 64 bits.` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)

Comment: @uzay95 The question is tagged "x86" so we are talking **specifically** about the Intel x86 architecture, in which a word is 16 bits wide. According to your article, even the x86_64 has a word size of 16 bits.

Comment: Thanx a lot , finally I understood this directive

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆再教育营六四事件法轮功郝海东 Did you figure out why `PTR` is needed?

Comment: @pmor nope. And I moved to GAS later as it is slightly more cross arch. Try asking Peter Cordes.

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com: In MASM and GAS `.intel_syntax`, `dword` is a constant with value `4`, so `mov dword [rdi], eax` is actually `mov [rdi + 4], eax`.  This sucks a lot (silent wrong-code), but so do other MASM syntax design decisions: *[Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129743)* - part of the need for `ptr` is to specify that it's a memory operand at all when there's no register involved: brackets *don't* do that.  NASM syntax doesn't have any of those problems so can be clean and simple.

Comment: @pmor: see my previous comment replying to Ciro.

Answer (score 11):

Consider [the figure enclosed in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395591/what-is-exactly-the-base-pointer-and-stack-pointer-to-what-do-they-point).
`ebp-4` is your first local variable and, seen as a dword pointer, it is the address of a 32 bit integer that has to be cleared.
Maybe your source starts with

```
Object x = null;
```

Answer (score 7):

It is a 32bit declaration. If you type at the top of an assembly file the statement [bits 32], then you don't need to type DWORD PTR. So for example:

```
[bits 32]
.
.
and  [ebp-4], 0
```