# ASM instruction seem not in standard syntax

Tags: assembly

while i was practicing reverse engineering on a crack-me i found myself confusing by this instruction

```
MOV DWORD PTR [6CCCDC],EDX
```

it shouldn't be allowed because the intel syntax is `MOV dest,src` 
Thanks for those who'll help;

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987876/what-does-dword-ptr-mean. (Size Directive)

Comment: Practice some more ;)

Comment: Assembly? There's not one thing called assembly and you must add the correct architecture tag in the question

Answer (score 1):

It's valid, and follows the syntax `MOV dest,src` you mention actually.

The easy part, `EDX` is the source, it reads the value from that CPU register.

Then `[6CCCDC]` is the destination. Note the square brackets, they means that the number is a **pointer** instead of an immediate value. So the destination is the memory address 0x6CCCDC.

`DWORD PTR` is a modifier that indicates the size of the data being operated on, 32 bits here. In this particular instruction, it's redundant, as the dword can be inferred from using EDX, a 32 bits register. Depending on the exact compiler, it may be optional or mandatory. It's useful in immediate-to-memory transfers as it specifies the width of the hardcoded constant.

In short, the whole instructions means "Take the value of the `EDX` register and put it in the 32 bits memory location beginning at 6CCCDC.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't it be allowed?

`EDX` is `src`, and `DWORD PTR [6CCCDC]` is dest. Therefore this moves `EDX` to `DWORD PTR [6CCCDC]`.