# Can someone explain the following assembly line to me? "and dword ptr[esi], 0xFF"

Tags: assembly, dword

I've got the following line of code in an assembly level language task:

```
and dword ptr[esi], 0xFF
```

From my understanding dword is 32 bits, and FF means we're storing 8 bits or 1 byte into `ptr[esi]`, but what's `ptr` and what is the purpose of using square brackets to reference our `esi` register?

Also, how does using an `and` change the meaning of the line?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987876/what-does-dword-ptr-mean.
Maybe it helps.

Comment: The type is not determined by the length of the string, it's a dword because you said it is

Comment: That does `*esi &= 0xff`, that is it clears the top 24 bits. You should do some research if you don't even know what square brackets mean.

Comment: Thanks for the link there Luci, I was having trouble finding anything involving ands. And thank you Jester for the response as well, however condescending it may be.

Comment: @Jester `*((dword *)esi) &= 0xFF;`   casperf1: without brackets the `and` instruction would affect the value in register `esi`, like `and esi,0xff` <=> `esi &= 0xFF;`. And the `and` is the crucial part of the line, it's the actual instruction, so it does change/define the meaning of line completely. It would be "store" if there would be `mov`, `and` is bit-wise arithmetic operation.

Comment: thank you @Ped7g. As far as I can tell from my research, dword prt is a size directive for a 32-bit integer, AND is (as you say) the arithmetic operator, and what this line is doing is ANDing the hex value FF(255) into the 4 bytes starting at the address in ESI.

Does that sound about right?

Comment: The `dword ptr` is used because without it, the assembler cannot know the size of the memory operand which `esi` is pointing to.

Comment: @casperf1 Yes, exactly. The size modifier is needed, because neither `[esi]` or `0xFF` can be used to deduce the "data width" of the operation. Compare with `and [esi],ax`  ... where `ax` contains the operand, so it's possible for assembler to deduce the correct "data width" is 16 bit in such case.

Comment: @casperf1 strictly speaking it ANDs the memory operand with `0x000000FF`.

Comment: that's perfect Weather Vane & Ped7g, thanks for the responses. Much appreciated.

@Ped7g, I'm a little curious, when you say `ax` contains an operand, do you mean an operand that specifies the size of the memory to be 16-bit?

Comment: `0xFF` is an *immediate* operand, whereas `ax` is a *register* operand, and `ax` is known by the assembler to be a 16-bit register, so its *content* is not what tells the assembler: `and word ptr[esi], ax` is simply unnecessary.

Comment: thanks again @WeatherVane

Comment: 0xFF is just a convenient way to write 0x000000FF.