# x86 intel assembly language, not fully understandable

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I've read and watched a lot of *youtube* videos without any progress.
I'm trying to learn from a site called *hackcenter* and they presented me with a question like this in assembly code.

```
testazza: //No idea what this is doing
.LFB0:  //No idea what this is doing either
        push    ebp 
        mov     ebp, esp //Creating the stack i guess
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8] //Moves 8bytes of memory allocation (Dont know what DWORD PTR DOES though)
        imul    eax, eax, -1795719608 //(Multiply what? Is -1795719608  a memory adress?                                       
        pop     ebp     //Pop the pointer                                                      
        ret   //Return
```

To be honest, I don't think there's enough explanation on this, so I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand what this program is actually doing.

Comment: The first to lines are labels, you should already know that. The `-1795719608` is just a number, `eax` is multiplies by that. PS: make sure you have an instruction set reference so you can look up what instructions do yourself.

Comment: imul eax, eax, constant is not an instruction. Check your work.

Comment: Consider reading an assembly tutorial. These questions are really basic and best answered by learning assembly programming in a systematic fashion.

Comment: @Joshua Some assemblers accept `imul` with two registers and an immediate if the two registers are equal, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I'm wondering if the -1795719608 is some "magic" number. If you look at the hackcenter example, is this explained?

Comment: While some particular topics may be better explained by video, overall the amount of information needed to learn x86 Assembly (not fully, just usable core of it relevant to user-land code, without OS/virtual machine management specifics) would be way too much for videos. You have to go through hundreds or thousand+ pages of book(s). Plus practising a lot by writing your own code. Watching videos is too slow compared to reading a good book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commented code. At entry, [esp+0] = 32 bit return address, [esp+4} = 32 bit parameter. After `push ebp` `mov ebp, esp`, [ebp+4] = 32 bit return address, [ebp+8] = 32 parameter (this is 32 bit `stdcall` calling convention). The imul is effectively an unsigned multiply because it only keeps the bottom 32 bits of what could be a 64 bit product, and the bottom 32 bits are the same for signed or unsigned multiply. So the signed integer -1795719608 is equivalent to the unsigned integer 2499247688.

```
testazza:                    ; probably function label
.LFB0:                       ; probably not needed
        push    ebp          ; save ebp
        mov     ebp, esp     ; ebp = esp after the push
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8] ;move first parameter (32 bit) into eax
        imul    eax, eax, -1795719608  ;eax = eax * -1795719608
                                   ; or eax = eax * 0x94F77E48
                             ; eax is returned value
        pop     ebp          ; restore ebp, esp                                                      
        ret                  ; return to caller
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn Assembly language for Intel x86 Architecture I fully recommend Assembly Language for x86 Processors by Kip R. Irvine. It is understandable and implements some libraries (e.g. Input/Output) in order to focus on more important topics of assembly language. ([link to the book on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133769402)).

Now, I will try to explain some parts of your code:

1. `imul    eax, eax, -1795719608` it means that you take the value of the register `eax` and multiply it by -1795719608 which is an integer number and then save the result in `eax` again.
2. `mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]`. For explain this line [see the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987876/what-does-dword-ptr-mean), maybe they give to you a better answer about it.