# assembly registers esp and ebp

Tags: assembly, intel, cpu-registers

I am currently learning assembly for Intel processors.
Since the stack 'grows down', why do we have to add in order to access a specific element

```
[ebp + 8] ;; This will access the first param
```

I konw we have to skip the old ebp value and the return address and that's why we use 8 ( because each are 4 bytes long ).
This is kinda strange.

Also, if **ebp** is a backup copy for **esp**, what is ebp's value in the main function
Ex:

```
_start:

;; what's ebp value here ?

push eax
push ebx
call someFunction ;; this will create a stack frame

+-----------+
|   param1  |
+-----------+
|   param0  | <--- this is [ebp + 8] ( assuming mov ebp, esp )
+-----------+
|ret_address|
+-----------+
|    ebp    |
+-----------+ <--- esp
```

And also when we allocate memory for locals, we have to substract from ebp ...
Please give a non-ambiguous answer.
Thank you!

Comment: A main() function is no different from a regular function, it has a prologue too.  You didn't show one in your assembly snippet, not sure why.  Space for locals is created by adjusting esp, not ebp.

Comment: There are same questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395591/what-is-exactly-the-base-pointer-and-stack-pointer-to-what-do-they-point , and other linked to it

Answer (score 14):

The initial value for `%ebp` is usually 0. This is so debuggers know when to end following the link chain in a backtrace.

You should think of `%ebp` as a reference point. For convenience, it is placed between the function arguments and local variables. That way, you access arguments with a positive offset, and variables with a negative offset, so it's easy to tell whether you are accessing a variable or an argument.

Comment: Why 0? Initial when CPU is powered on?

Comment: `%ebp` is usually initialized to 0 by either the loader or the runtime library. That initialization to 0 is sometimes specified in a formal document (e.g: IIRC the ELF x86 psABI specifies it).

Comment: what loader or what runtime? If you are talking about specific OS, please explicitly state it. On my OS `ebp` isn't initialized to 0, at least in user-mode. Also, to be precise, register name is `ebp`, not `%ebp`. `%` is a prefix for register name.

Comment: btw, there is `intel` tag, so why do you use AT&T syntax?

Comment: @Abyx: note I wrote _usually_, though if your system doesn't initialize EBP, I wonder how debuggers are supposed to stop backtracing. In Linux, it's apparently done by `libc`. As to why I use `%ebp`, it's mostly an inconscious reflex.

Answer (score 3):

Just as you said, the stack grows down.  So, you subtract to grow the stack down for locals.  You add to look back in the stack for elements stored there.