# Strange assembly calling convention

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention

```
push ebx
push ebp
mov ebp,[esp+14]
push esi
mov esi,[esp+14]
push edi
mov [esp+10],00000000
cmp dword ptr [ebp+00],05
jne aheadInThisFx
mov eax,[esp+20]
mov edi,[ebp+08]
push eax
push edi
push esi
call SomeItherFx
//more code
aheadInThisFx:
```

The code above is the disassembly of the start of a function, it is very strange. What kind of compiler would generate such nonsense ?
If you already encountered something alike, please explain it to me too.
I don't understand the calling convention.
At line 3, what does it mean to: 
`mov ebp,[esp+14]`
shouldn't it be: 
`push ebp
mov ebp,esp`
 
and the arguments, [ebp-4], [ebp-8] ?
Thanks

Comment: Apparently it's using `ebp` as a general purpose register. Calling convention doesn't mandate a frame pointer, nor a standard stack frame.

Comment: Imagine a stack. ESP is the offset of the uppermost element on the stack. [esp+14] references the value that is saved 7 words below ESP.

Comment: See [What is exactly the base pointer and stack pointer? To what do they point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395591/), specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1395646/902497) which discusses frame pointer omission (FPO).

Answer (score 0):

The usual x86-32 calling conventions only specify how the arguments need to be laid out on the stack, who removes them and which registers have to be preserved. In particular a frame pointer is not typically required and code may use `ebp` as just another callee-saved register. The arguments can be accessed relative to `esp`, knowing the stack layout prescribed by the convention and any stack adjustments made by your own code.

This is far from "nonsense", it's a frequent optimization. Given that x86-32 doesn't give you very many registers, it makes sense not to waste `ebp` for a frame pointer if it's otherwise not required.

As for the quoted code, `ebx`, `ebp`, `esi` and `edi` are pushed because they are callee-saved registers. I assume the numbers are in hex, so the `mov ebp,[esp+14]` loads the 3rd argument, since stack layout at that point, starting from `esp`, is: `ebp`, `ebx`, `return address`, `arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`. Similarly, the `mov esi,[esp+14]` will load the 2nd argument because by that point `esi` will also be on the stack.

Comment: Still assuming the numbers are in hex, any ideas why a function would zero its return address? (**mov [esp+10],00000000**)

Comment: @user3144770 nice catch ... I have no idea.