# Why do we "PUSH EBP" and "MOV EBP, ESP" in the CALLEE in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-registers

Why do we `push ebp` as the first action in the Callee of an Assembly function?

I understand that then we use `mov edi, [ebp+8]` to get the passed in variables, but our `esp` is already pointing to return address of the Caller function. We can easily access the passed in variables with `mov edi, [esp+4]` or if we pushed the Callee registers, then `mov edi, [esp+16]`.

So, why have that extra register in the cpu (the `ebp`) which you later have to manage in functions? i.e.

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

...

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

Comment: You don't have to. Compilers will often omit the frame pointer nowadays, if the function doesn't use variable length arrays or `alloca()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is exactly the base pointer and stack pointer? To what do they point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395591/what-is-exactly-the-base-pointer-and-stack-pointer-to-what-do-they-point)

Comment: Why did you put "CALLEE" in all-caps in the title?  Are you wondering why the caller doesn't make stack frames as part of the calling convention?  It doesn't sound that way, based on the text other than the title.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is establishing a new [**stack frame**](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames) within the callee, while preserving the stack frame of the caller. A stack frame allows consistent access to passed parameters and local variables using fixed offsets relative to `EBP` anywhere in the function, while `ESP` is free to continue being modified as needed while the function is running. `ESP` is a moving target, so accessing parameters and variables using dynamic offsets relative to `ESP` can be tricky, if not impossible, depending on how the function uses the stack.  Creating a stack frame is generally safer, at the cost of using a few bytes of stack space to preserve the pointer to the caller's stack frame.

Comment: The cost of keeping a frame pointer is not in the single `push [r/e]bp`, it's giving up free use of a caller-saved register on a register-starved (or *very* register starved, for 32-bit) architecture.

Comment: Having a dynamic offset to the variables might be confusing to humans, but is it really necessary for a Compiler? Is the overhead really worth it?

Comment: @EOF `[R/E]BP` is reserved specifically for use as a stack frame pointer. It is not a generic purpose register, like `[R/E]AX`, for instance.

Comment: @ArturGrigio the compiler can't always know at compile-time how much data has been pushed on the stack at run-time (for example, allocating stack space dynamically, which is non-standard but is supported by some compilers, such as for variable-length stack-based arrays and `alloca()`), so using offsets relative to `ESP` is not always feisible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Have you ever looked at the assembly generated by a modern compiler (like `gcc` or `clang`) on high optimization settings (including `-fomit-frame-pointer`)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The point is, `[r/e]bp` **is** a perfectly normal general-purpose register.

Comment: @EOF only when stack frames are not being used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: No. `[r/e]bp` **is** a general-purpose register like any other. It is *used* as the frame pointer *by convention*.

Comment: @EOF: the `enter` and `leave` instructions provide ISA support for that convention, but they're not worth using unless optimizing for code-size instead of speed.  (Using stack frames can save code size, even though it costs insns to set up and tear down, because addressing modes using `[e/rsp (+disp8/disp32)]` have to use a SIB byte even though there's no index register.  The encoding that would mean `[rsp]` instead means "there's a SIB byte".)  So this convention has permeated its way into the ISA to some degree.  Fortunately there's nothing really enforcing it, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes: If that precluded `rbp` from being a general-purpose register, then `r13` and `r12` would also not be general purpose, since they too require special casing for memory access through them (due to having the same `ModR/M` byte as `rsp` and `rbp`, respectively).

Comment: @EOF: agreed.  I usually say that x86-64 has 15 general purpose registers.  Being the best/only choice for some special purposes doesn't necessarily mean they're not general purpose.  Almost all of the low 8 regs have some instruction that treats them specially, other than rbx and rbp (if you only count useful instructions.  i.e. excluding `xlat` (rbx) and `enter` / `leave`).  My point was just that the choice of `rbp` as the base pointer isn't arbitrary; there are ISA reasons for it.  (Moreso in 32bit code, where you wouldn't want to choose one that was sometimes needed for a special purpose)

Comment: @PeterCordes: And I agree in turn, but my point is that using a frame pointer at all is a colossal waste for 99% of functions.

Comment: @EOF: agreed on that, too!  I always /facepalm at all the newbie questions that make stack frames for no reason, esp. in 64bit mode where the stack pointer doesn't tend to change in the first place.  In a function with a lot of instructions that reference the stack, though, it can be a code-size win, but usually still not a performance win.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: you said in a comment that variable-length arrays are non-standard.  That's incorrect: they're specified by C99.  You're right that `alloca` is non-standard.  The Linux man page says it's not specified by POSIX, and cites its origins as BSD.

Answer (score 3):

The given answer from Remy is perfect, however here is one small addition, a thing you might also see right after

```
mov ebp, esp
```

it's very possible to see instruction such:

```
sub esp, 20h   ; creating space for local variables with size 20h
sub esp, CCh   ; creating space for local variables with size CCh
```

along side with an AND call sometimes (like and esp, 0FFFFFFF0h). This is also part of the dealing with the stack and it's done so the stack can be align and be divisible by 16.
Of course all this depends on the used calling convention (cdecl, fastcall, stdcall etc.)