# Passing arguments and results for function as %rax or through stack - x64 AT&T assembly

Tags: assembly, att

im trying to do a simple program calculating a recursive function where:

1. X1 = -1
2. X2 = -2
3. Xn = X(n-1) * X(n-2)

Using x64 assembly. I have two problems i cant come up with solution for:

- a) how can i make it like a "real" function - argument passed in
  %rax, function result located in %rax. As you can see for now my
  argument is passed through %rdi and result is in %rax.
- b) how can i pass the argument and results through stack? i tried it
  but failed (stack-version lines are commented out). it has something
  to do with calculating address i suppose, could someone modify it so
  i get the grasp how it should have been done?

  ```
  .data
  SYSREAD = 0
  SYSWRITE = 1
  SYSEXIT = 60
  NUMBER = 4

  STDOUT = 1 
  STDIN = 0

  EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

  .text
  .global main

   main:
  # --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
  mov $0, %rax
  mov $0, %r15
  mov $0, %rdi
  mov $NUMBER, %rdi

  # push %rdi
  call recursion
  # pop %rax
  jmp end

  # --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
                                  # function
                                  # X1 = -1
                                  # X2 = -2
                                  # Xn = X(n-1) razy X(n-2)
                                  # input   => %rax = n
                                  # output  => %rax = X(n)
  recursion:
  # pop %rdi

  cmp $1, %rdi                    # is n = 1? 
  je recursion_end_1

  cmp $2, %rdi                    # is n = 2?
  je recursion_end_2
                                  # n in %rdi
  dec %rdi                        # (n-1)
  push %rdi                       # (n-1) into stack
  call recursion

  pop %rdi                        # (n-1) in %rdi
  dec %rdi                        # (n-2)
  push %rax                       # (n-2) into stack
  call recursion

  pop %rcx                        # value of (n-2)
  imul %rcx                       # multiplication
  push %rax
  jmp recursion_end               # result in %rax

  recursion_end_1:
  mov $-1, %rax                   # n = 1
  ret

  recursion_end_2:
  mov $-2, %rax                   # n = 2
  ret

  recursion_end:
  ret

  # --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---

  end:
  movq $SYSEXIT, %rax             # wychodzenie
  movq $EXIT_SUCCESS, %rdi
  syscall
  ```

Comment: "real" functions **do** get the first argument in `rdi` as per the normal sysv abi convention.

Comment: About stack: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1395591/4271923  By the very first `pop %rdi` inside `recursion` you are taking return address out of stack, not argument (arguments are above that, so `mov rdi,[rsp+8]` is probably close to what you want). Don't hesitate to step into this code in debugger, and watch values in `rsp` + open memory window to that area, to see how those values are written into memory + how `push/pop/call/ret` operates. Every minute of poking around in debugger usually equals to 10 minutes of reading/explaining.