# Retrieve arguments 5 & 6 from a C++ function call in masm proc

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, masm, calling-convention

Given:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int AddAsm(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f);

int main()
{
    std::cout << AddAsm(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
}
```

I want to implemet the AddAsm function in x64 masm like this:

```
.code
    AddAsm proc
        mov rax, 0
        add rax, rcx
        add rax, rdx
        add rax, r8
        add rax, r9

        add rax, qword ptr [rsp + 32]
        add rax, qword ptr [rsp + 40]
        add rax, qword ptr [rsp + 48]
        add rax, qword ptr [rsp + 56]
        ret
    AddAsm endp
end
```

Now everything is clear for the first 4 parameters, but I can't manage to understand/find a practical example on how the rest of the parameters are put on the stack, what does the `rbp` and `rsp` register values actually represent and what are the offsets from one parameter to another.

Can somebody please shed some light with an example, please?

Comment: FYI: [x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention). `rsp` and `rbp` are registers in the CPU (remember them as "stack pointer" and "base pointer"). Both play a role in addressing of parameters and local variables which are stored in memory.

Comment: FYI: [What exactly is the base pointer and stack pointer? To what do they point?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395591/7478597) It's not matching exactly (it's about x86 and the language is C) but it gives a general idea...

Comment: Concerning _I can't manage to understand/find a practical example on how the rest of the parameters are put on the stack_ Actually, I expected something like "push" or so but the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jGxzfxhbn) uncovered that it's done a bit differently: The stack pointer is increased beforehand, then the values are `mov`ed into there stores. There is for sure a reason why the pro's decided to do it this way... ;-)

Comment: Side note: `lea eax, [rcx+rdx]` can replace your first 3 instructions.  Or if you don't want to use LEA, start with `mov eax, [rsp+40]` (the first stack arg, above the return address above the red zone) or `mov eax,ecx`.  A compiler should show you working asm, like the Godbolt link in Scheff's comment.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat: Windows x64 uses shadow space, so it's rather inconvenient to use `push` to set up args.  You want to reserve shadow space once in the prologue for all calls you make, so RSP isn't pointing at the memory where stack args are stored.  So you also reserve enough space for stack args for the function call with the most args.  And IIRC, Windows x64 stack-unwind metadata normally wants you not to move RSP except in the function prologue/epilogue.  For a simple function with only one callee that doesn't also reserve space for local vars, `push` then `sub rsp, 32` would be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
.code
    AddAsm proc
        mov eax, 0
        add eax, ecx ; a
        add eax, edx ; b
        add eax, r8d ; c
        add eax, r9d ; d
        add eax, dword ptr [rsp + 40] ; e
        add eax, dword ptr [rsp + 48] ; f
        ret
    AddAsm endp
end
```

Comment: maybe you should provide some information about your code: why e and f stored in rsp + 40 and +48? (considering that the author of the question wants an explanation)