# Why does leave do "mov esp,ebp" in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

It's said that the `leave` instruction is the same as :

```
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
```

But what is `mov esp,ebp` here for? It doesn't seem valid to me...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579262/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ebp-frame-pointer-register

Answer (score 94, accepted):

`mov esp,ebp` sets the stack pointer to the base frame address, effectively releasing the whole frame. (Don't forget that this is Intel syntax, the destination comes first.) If you didn't do it, once you call `ret`, you would still be using the called function's stack frame with your calling function, with crashtastic consequences.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't `mov esp,ebp` set the base pointer to the stack pointer's address? `mov ebp,esp` would update the stack pointer to point at the base frame.

Comment: @Decave, it depends on if you use AT&T-style disassembly or Intel-style disassembly. Since the instructions don't have length suffixes and the registers are not prefixed with `%`, we're talking about Intel-style, where destination comes first. The equivalent AT&T-style disassembly for this question, which you are probably thinking of and where destination comes last, would be `movl %ebp, %esp`.

Comment: Your site https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ is down (so is the whole domain). Are you planning to get it back up, or should I start editing links in old answers? (Unfortunately old comments linking instructions aren't editable.)

Comment: @PeterCordes this is not intentional and news to me, will look into it this evening (PST).

Comment: @PeterCordes DNS did not autorenew for sad reasons, should be back online as soon as TTL expires and refreshes. (It's already back online for me.)

Comment: Excellent, thanks for hosting that nice resource. :)

Comment: @PeterCordes of course! thank you for letting me know it was down. If you want, you can send me an email (address on website) and I'll give you other addresses to try if felixcloutier.com goes down; I'm usually more responsive over email than over SO.

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue is the fact that there are two different ways of writing x86 assembly. One is the AT&T notation and the other is the Intel notation. The order of the arguments to an instruction are reversed in Intel notation as opposed to AT&T. Your version of the assembly appears to be in Intel notation, which means that `mov esp, ebp` actaully moves the value in `ebp` to `esp`. In the more logical (in my opinion) AT&T notation it would be `mov %ebp, %esp`.

Comment: It would be `movd` instead of `mov`, too.

Comment: It's "more logical" if you view the semantics as `move ebp into esp`.  The "Intel" notation (which predates Intel by a loooooooooooong time -- for example the Interdata 16-bit series which dates back to the '60s uses exactly this format and was by no means the first...) has semantics more like `move such that esp = ebp`.

Comment: @zneak, incorrect.  `movd` is actually an MMX instruction.  If you wanted to include a size suffix (which in this case is *optional*, mind you) you'd use `movl`

Comment: In fact Intel style notation is much more common. All other assembly languages I know have destination comes first. You can think it as an assignment. `esp = ebp`

Comment: I realized early on that Intel X86 assembly uses what we used to call Reverse Polish Notation, which caused much confusion among business majors who were accustomed to the more "English-like" right to left notation used in algebra, and to operate Texas Instruments calculators. Conversely, the Hewlett-Packard calculators catered to engineers and used Reverse Polish Notation. As I began to learn to use various assemblers, I soon discovered that most of them also use Reverse Polish. That included Univac Exec-8 assembly and IBM BAL (Basic Assembly Language), used on IBM 360/370 class mainframes.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray: Not RPN for sure, in RPN the operands precede the operation, I don't know of any assembly language that does this.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler use this instruction to free the used space by the function in the stack, the `leave` instruction has the same behavior as `mov esp, ebp` with `pop ebp`.

Comment: Surely `enter` and `leave` cannot **both** be for the purpose of freeing the used space on the stack?

Comment: Yes you are right, just the leave instruction, I made a mistake