# "enter" vs "push ebp; mov ebp, esp; sub esp, imm" and "leave" vs "mov esp, ebp; pop ebp"

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, micro-optimization, stack-frame

What is the difference between the `enter` and

```
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
sub  esp, imm
```

instructions? Is there a performance difference? If so, which is faster and why do compilers always use the latter?

Similarly with the `leave` and

```
mov  esp, ebp
pop  ebp
```

instructions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474355/about-leave-in-x86-assembly?rq=1

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is a performance difference, especially for `enter`. On modern processors this decodes to some 10 to 20 µops, while the three instruction sequence is about 4 to 6, depending on the architecture. For details consult [Agner Fog's](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) instruction tables.

Additionally the `enter` instruction usually has a quite high latency, for example 8 clocks on a core2, compared to the 3 clocks dependency chain of the three instruction sequence.

Furthermore the three instruction sequence may be spread out by the compiler for scheduling purposes, depending on the surrounding code of course, to allow more parallel execution of instructions.

Comment: May I ask where you get this information? And what about for `leave`?

Comment: See http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf for a global overview how the processor executes code and http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf for detailed instruction latencies. `leave` is on some architectures equal in performance, but AFAIK in no case faster. It consumes less memory in the instruction cache, though

Comment: If the 3 instruction sequence is faster than `enter`, what is the point of it?

Comment: Compatibility. It has been around since the 8086 and it most likely for ever will. The same goes for the `loop` instruction: It is way slower than `dec reg; jnz`, but it is still there because some old software might possibly use it.

Comment: Enter/leave were not in the 8086/8.  I believe they were added in the 80186/8 as those (rarely used) chips had all the real mode instructions of the iapx286 (which is well documented to have enter/leave).

Comment: There isn't a 3-cycle dependency chain for `push ebp` / `mov ebp,esp` / `sub esp, imm`.  The `mov` in the middle has to read the modified ESP from `push` (costing a stack-sync uop on Intel), but it does *not* modify ESP itself.  `sub esp, imm` can thus execute in parallel with the `mov`.  The stack engine (since Pentium-M) also means `push ebp` doesn't have a separate latency cost for ESP, it's just another stack offset added to the one from the `call` that reached this code in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

When designing the 80286, Intel's CPU designers decided to add two instructions to help maintain displays.

Here the micro code inside the CPU:

```
; ENTER Locals, LexLevel

push    bp              ;Save dynamic link.
mov     tempreg, sp     ;Save for later.
cmp     LexLevel, 0     ;Done if this is lex level zero.
je      Lex0

lp:
dec     LexLevel
jz      Done            ;Quit if at last lex level.
sub     bp, 2           ;Index into display in prev act rec
push    [bp]            ; and push each element there.
jmp     lp              ;Repeat for each entry.

Done:
push    tempreg         ;Add entry for current lex level.

Lex0:
mov     bp, tempreg     ;Ptr to current act rec.
sub     sp, Locals      ;Allocate local storage
```

Alternative to ENTER would be:

; enter n, 0    ;14 cycles on the 486

```
push    bp              ;1 cycle on the 486
sub     sp, n           ;1 cycle on the 486
```

; enter n, 1    ;17 cycles on the 486

```
push    bp              ;1 cycle on the 486
push    [bp-2]          ;4 cycles on the 486
mov     bp, sp          ;1 cycle on the 486
add     bp, 2           ;1 cycle on the 486
sub     sp, n           ;1 cycle on the 486
```

; enter n, 3    ;23 cycles on the 486

```
push    bp              ;1 cycle on the 486
push    [bp-2]          ;4 cycles on the 486
push    [bp-4]          ;4 cycles on the 486
push    [bp-6]          ;4 cycles on the 486
mov     bp, sp          ;1 cycle on the 486
add     bp, 6           ;1 cycle on the 486
sub     sp, n           ;1 cycle on the 486
```

Etc. The long way might increase your file size, but is way quicker.

One last note, programmer don't really use display anymore since that was a very slow work around, making ENTER pretty useless now.

Source: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH12/CH12-3.html

Comment: The "; enter n, 0 ;14 cycles on the 486" example is missing the `mov bp, sp` line. And `enter` and `leave` appeared on the 186, not 286.

Comment: Here is a [PDF with the 80186 instruction set](https://www.jamieiles.com/80186/development-guide.pdf) and we can find the ENTER and LEAVE instructions in it. Interestingly enough, I found [this 286 book](http://bitsavers.org/components/intel/80286/210498-001_iAPX_286_Programmers_Reference_1983.pdf) which says that the instructions were brand new in the 80286 processor. So I can understand the confusion.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Intel documentation for later CPUs typically pretends 186 didn't exist; it was only intended for embedded stuff, not mainstream PCs which ran the same applications as 8086 and 286 PCs.

Answer (score 8):

**`enter` is unusably slow on all CPUs,** nobody uses it except maybe for code-size optimization at the expense of speed.  (If a frame pointer is needed at all, or desired to allow more compact addressing modes for addressing stack space.)

**`leave` *is* fast enough to be worth using**, and GCC *does* use it (if ESP / RSP isn't already pointing at a saved EBP/RBP; otherwise it just uses `pop ebp`).

`leave` is only 3 uops on modern Intel CPUs (and 2 on some AMD).  (https://agner.org/optimize/, https://uops.info/).

mov / pop is only 2 uops total (on modern x86 where a "stack engine" tracks updates to ESP/RSP).  So `leave` is just one more uop than doing things separately.  I've tested this on Skylake, comparing a call/ret in a loop with the function setting up a traditional frame pointer and tearing down its stack frame using `mov`/`pop` or `leave`. `perf` counters for `uops_issued.any` shows one more front-end uop when you use leave than for mov/pop. (I ran my own test in case other measurement methods has been counting a stack-sync uop in their leave measurements, but using it in a real function controls for that.)

Possible reasons why older CPUs might have benefited more keeping mov / pop split up:

- In most CPUs without a uop cache (i.e. Intel before Sandybridge, AMD before Zen), multi-uop instructions can be a decode bottleneck.  They can only decode in the first ("complex") decoder, so might mean the decode cycle before that produced fewer uops than normal.
- Some Windows calling conventions are callee-pops stack args, using `ret n`.  (e.g. `ret 8` to do ESP/RSP += 8 after popping the return address).  This is a multi-uop instruction, unlike plain near `ret` on modern x86.  So the above reason goes double: leave and `ret 12` couldn't decode in the same cycle
- Those reasons also apply to legacy decode to build uop-cache entries.
- P5 Pentium also preferred a RISC-like subset of x86, being unable to even break up complex instructions into separate uops *at all*.

**For modern CPUs**, `leave` takes up 1 extra uop in the uop cache.  And all 3 have to be in the same line of the uop cache, which could lead to only partial filling of the previous line.  So larger x86 code size *could* actually improve packing into the uop cache.  Or not, depending on how things line up.

Saving 2 bytes (or 3 in 64-bit mode) may or may not be worth 1 extra uop per function.

GCC favours `leave`, clang and MSVC favour `mov`/`pop` (even with `clang -Oz` code-size optimization even at the expense of speed, e.g. doing stuff like `push 1 / pop rax` (3 bytes) instead of 5-byte `mov eax,1`).

ICC favours mov/pop, but with `-Os` will use `leave`.  https://godbolt.org/z/95EnP3G1f

Answer (score 7):

There is no real speed advantage using either of them, though the long method will probably run better due to the fact CPU's these days are more 'optimized' to the shorter simpler instructions that are more generic in use (plus it allows saturation of the execution ports if your lucky).

The advantage of `LEAVE` (which is still used, just see the windows dlls) is that its smaller than manually tearing down a stack frame, this helps a lot when your space is limited.

The Intel instruction manuals (volume 2A to be precise) will have more nitty gritty details on the instructions, so should [Dr Agner Fogs Optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/)

Comment: I tested the `ENTER` vs `PUSH/MOV` on my Xeon and I get about 2x difference. So if you have a loop in the millions over a `CALL`, it would start to be slightly different. With 100 million iterations (what I tried), it's like 1 second. So if you have `CALL`s within the call, it multiplies the delay... I think that for a compiler, it's definitely a good optimization.