# Why is there no companion instruction to leave?

Tags: assembly, x86, cdecl

Why is there no companion instruction to leave on the x86? That way,

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp,%ebp
pushl   $3
popl    %eax
leave
ret
```

could become:

```
enter #or something
pushl   $3
popl    %eax
leave
ret
```

Isn't that just faster in general?

Comment: first code is faster . see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959890/enter-vs-push-ebp-mov-ebp-esp-sub-esp-imm-and-leave-vs-mov-esp-ebp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact, there **is** an [`enter` instruction](http://www.piclist.com/techref/intel/x86/inst/enters.htm). As to why it's not seeing much use, ["Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual"](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html) offers a hint:

> Assembly/ Compiler Coding Rule 32. (MH impact, M generality) Use `push`/`pop` to manage stack space and address adjustments between function calls/returns instead of `enter`/`leave`. Using `enter` instruction with non-zero immediates can experience significant delays in the pipeline in addition to misprediction.

Comment: `leave` is not slow so GCC *does* use it when it made a frame pointer, if ESP isn't already pointing at a saved EBP.  `leave` is 3 uops, vs. 2 uops for separate `mov %ebp,%esp` / `pop %ebp`.  But yes, `enter` is terrible, even `enter 0,0` is 12 uops on Haswell/Skylake.  (https://agner.org/optimize/ ; https://uops.info/)

Answer (score 4):

There is indeed a matching [ENTER](http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH12/CH12-3.html#HEADING3-73) (Art of Assembly Language) instruction. It's seldom used however, because it is very slow, as explained in the link.

Answer (score 1):

There is `enter`, for some processors.

Comment: IIRC, it was introduced on x86 with the 80186/80188 processors.