# Mixing C and Assembly

Tags: c, assembly

I'm doing a program in assembly to read a disk through ports (0x1f0-0x1f7) and I'm mixing it with c. I have a function in assembly that I will call in my c main funtion. My main function as 1 parameter: sectors to read:

Kernel.c

```
extern int _readd(int nmrsector);
(...)
int sector = 257;
int error = _readd(sector);
if(error == 0) PrintString("Error"); //It is declared on my screen.h file
```

disk.asm

```
global _readd

_readd:
 push eax
 push ebx
 push ecx
 push edx
 push ebp

 mov ebp, esp
 mov eax, [ebp+8]
 mov ecx, eax
 cmp ecx, 256
 jg short _fail
 jne short _good

_fail:
 xor eax, eax
 leave
 ret

_good:
 xor eax, eax
 mov eax, 12
 leave
 ret
```

It crashes when run it with VirtualBox. Any ideas?

Comment: *How* do you run it in VirtualBox? You might want to try it using [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) which has hooks that allows you to use a debugger.

Comment: You don't use stack frames correctly. Read up how `ENTER` and `LEAVE` work. After your `leave`, you still have everything pushed on the stack.

Comment: I poped everything and it is always returning me error. When I change my sector to 25 it should return an int different than 0 but it is returning 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had to ovewrite registers.

Comment: `mov eax, [ebp+8]` is essentially a `mov eax, ecx`. You screwed up the stack setup dude.

Comment: See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to calling conventions.  You only need to save/restore some of the regs you use.  But more importantly, you have to actually `pop` them, in reverse order to the order you pushed, so the data comes back off the stack into the original locations.  You could also simplify the branching by conditionally jumping over `mov eax, 12`.  The good/fail paths are the same after that, and can rejoin each other without any jumps.  You *don't* need to make a traditional `enter` / `leave` stack frame, and use `[esp + offset]` for the arg

Answer (score 2):

If you save CPU registers when you enter a function, you need to restore them when you are finished. Your `PUSH`s need to be matched with `POP`s.

Also, if you use a stack frame to access local variables and parameters, setup the frame (`push ebp ; mov ebp, esp`) before everything, so you can more easily refer to them. Here `[ebp+8]` doesn't refer to a parameter, because you alter the stack before setting up the frame.

Comment: You should not use `enter` either.

Comment: @Ven Why not ? OP **did** use a stack frame, so I explain how to do it correctly. The fact that you can do everything without a stack frame is irrelevant.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm talking about. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26323663/1737909)

Comment: @Ven That's even worse. Downvoting for a minor performance detail isn't really useful. Anyway, edited the answer to focus more on OP' problem, and didn't mention `enter`.

Comment: it's "obsolete but are still supported for backwards compatibility reasons". anyway, removed my downvote, as it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: @Ven I'm curious if there is any official statement that `enter` is obsolete/not recommended. `leave` is widely used, and it doesn't make any sense to obsolete only half of an instruction pair. Do you have any source in mind ? About the downvote, your comments are welcome, it's just that I think it's not good to downvote when it doesn't challenge the answer at any point.