# Tiny C Compiler's generated code emits extra (unnecessary?) NOPs and JMPs

Tags: c, assembly, x86, compiler-optimization, tcc

Can someone explain why this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

when compiled with tcc using ***tcc code.c*** produces this asm:

```
00401000  |.  55               PUSH EBP
00401001  |.  89E5             MOV EBP,ESP
00401003  |.  81EC 00000000    SUB ESP,0
00401009  |.  90               NOP
0040100A  |.  B8 00000000      MOV EAX,0
0040100F  |.  E9 00000000      JMP fmt_vuln1.00401014
00401014  |.  C9               LEAVE
00401015  |.  C3               RETN
```

I guess that

```
00401009  |.  90   NOP
```

is maybe there for some memory alignment, but what about

```
0040100F  |.  E9 00000000     JMP fmt_vuln1.00401014
00401014  |.  C9              LEAVE
```

I mean why would compiler insert this near jump that jumps to the **next** instruction, LEAVE would execute anyway?

I'm on 64-bit Windows generating 32-bit executable using TCC 0.9.26.

Comment: It's actually the opposite of optimization, as you didn't turn it on. EDIT: apparently you can't control optimization with `tcc`. Ugh. Well, it's supposed to be tiny, not generating efficient code :)

Comment: TCC isn't (and shouldn't be) used for highly optimized building. It doesn't do much optimizations.

Comment: @Jester well it would be tinier without it and all the unecessary 00 bytes at the end..

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i know, i'm just curious what's the point of this

Comment: It is tcc that is tiny and fast, not the code it produces. Tcc is good for compiling things which will not be executed enough times to make it worth spending time on generating good code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Win10 x64

Comment: Strange I don't see this kind of code generated on Windows

Comment: Ok i examined it and saw that both .text and .data sections are 0x200 bytes long, so i guess i answered my 2nd question about all the extra 00s

Comment: @MichaelPetch that's weird, all my tcc programs have that jump-leave thing at functions epilogues

Comment: @MichaelPetch v0.9.26

Comment: I installed 0.9.26 and see what you are referring to. Seems the `jmp` has been eliminated in 0.9.27

Comment: is there win binary?

Comment: main() in general is not a function you should examine for this kind of thing, as compilers can/will look for it and add extra stuff.  For these tests use some other non-standard name like test or fun or foo or bar.  And tcc is not a compiler to really be looking at output of other than is it functional, not is it efficient.

Comment: did the code produced functionally match the high level language?

Comment: `tcc` and *optimization* are contradictory. Use an optimizing compiler (e.g. `gcc -O2` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) if you want optimizations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Superfluous JMP before the Function Epilogue

The *JMP* at the bottom that goes to the next statement, this was [fixed in a commit](http://repo.or.cz/tinycc.git/commitdiff/71b622096334e5cb90efd3c184654cb5d65682ae?hp=0a402f6e91c284dd37cb61e726cc95de20fe895e). [Version 0.9.27](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/tinycc/) of TCC resolves this issue:

> When 'return' is the last statement of the top-level block
>   (very common and often recommended case) jump is not needed.

As for the reason it existed in the first place? The idea is that each function has a possible common exit point. If there is a block of code with a return in it at the bottom, the *JMP* goes to a common exit point where stack cleanup is done and the `ret` is executed. Originally the code generator also emitted the *JMP* instruction erroneously at the end of the function too if it appeared just before the final `}` (closing brace). The fix checks to see if there is a `return` statement followed by a closing brace at the top level of the function. If there is, the *JMP* is omitted

An example of code that has a return at a lower scope before a closing brace:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc == 3) {
      argc++;
      return argc;
  }
  argc += 3;
  return argc;
}
```

The generated code looks like:

```
  401000:       55                      push   ebp
  401001:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
  401003:       81 ec 00 00 00 00       sub    esp,0x0
  401009:       90                      nop
  40100a:       8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
  40100d:       83 f8 03                cmp    eax,0x3
  401010:       0f 85 11 00 00 00       jne    0x401027
  401016:       8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
  401019:       89 c1                   mov    ecx,eax
  40101b:       40                      inc    eax
  40101c:       89 45 08                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],eax
  40101f:       8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]

  ; Jump to common function exit point. This is the `return argc` inside the if statement
  401022:       e9 11 00 00 00          jmp    0x401038

  401027:       8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
  40102a:       83 c0 03                add    eax,0x3
  40102d:       89 45 08                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],eax
  401030:       8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]

  ; Jump to common function exit point. This is the `return argc` at end of the function 
  401033:       e9 00 00 00 00          jmp    0x401038

  ; Common function exit point
  401038:       c9                      leave
  401039:       c3                      ret
```

In versions **prior** to 0.9.27 the `return argc` inside the if statement would jump to a common exit point (function epilogue). As well the `return argc` at the bottom of the function also jumps to the same common exit point of the function. The problem is that the common exit point for the function happens to be right after the top level `return argc`so the side effect is an extra JMP that happens to be to the next instruction.

---

### NOP after Function Prologue

The *NOP* isn't for alignment. Because of the way Windows implements [guard pages for the stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227153(v=vs.60).aspx) (Programs that are in Portable Executable format) TCC has two types of prologues. If the local stack space required < 4096 (smaller than a single page) then you see this kind of code generated:

```
401000:       55                      push   ebp
401001:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
401003:       81 ec 00 00 00 00       sub    esp,0x0
```

The `sub esp,0` isn't optimized out. It is the amount of stack space needed for local variables (in this case 0). If you add some local variables you will see the 0x0 in the *SUB* instruction changes to coincide with the amount of stack space needed for local variables. This prologue requires 9 bytes. There is another prologue to handle the case where the stack space needed is >= 4096 bytes. If you add an array of 4096 bytes with something like:

```
char somearray[4096]
```

and look at the resulting instruction you will see the function prologue change to a 10 byte prologue:

```
401000:       b8 00 10 00 00          mov    eax,0x1000
401005:       e8 d6 00 00 00          call   0x4010e0
```

TCC's code generator assumes that the function prologue is always 10 bytes when targeting WinPE. This is primarily because TCC is a single pass compiler. The compiler doesn't know how much stack space a function will use until **after** the function is processed. To get around not knowing this ahead of time, TCC pre-allocates 10 bytes for the prologue to fit the largest method. Anything shorter is padded to 10 bytes.

In the case where stack space needed < 4096 bytes the instructions used total 9 bytes. The *NOP* is used to pad the prologue to 10 bytes. For the case where >= 4096 bytes are needed, the number of bytes is passed in *EAX* and the function [`__chkstk`](http://repo.or.cz/tinycc.git/blob/HEAD:/win32/lib/chkstk.S) is called to allocate the required stack space instead.

Comment: Might be worth summarizing the comments in your answer: TCC is not an optimizing compiler.  The JMP is not the only silly thing here, almost all the rest of the instructions here are ridiculous.  e.g. it doesn't even look for [the peephole optimization of `xor`-zeroing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and), not to mention a useless `sub esp,0` and even a NOP!  Obviously it doesn't *need* to make / destroy a stack frame, but there are valid arguments for that even in optimized code.

Comment: @PeterCordes I could discuss all those things but that is all secondary to the JMP instruction which was asked for.If you wish to summarize the other stuff in another answer be my guest. TCC does in fact do some level of optimization. Not usually on instructions but it will attempt to inline code in the same module among other things. To say it doesn't optimize at all would be incorrect.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I haven't looked at TCC or its asm output other than this question.

Answer (score 8):

**TCC is *not* an optimizing compiler**, at least not really.  Every single instruction it emitted for `main` is sub-optimal or not needed at all, except the `ret`.  IDK why you thought the JMP was the only instruction that might not make sense for performance.

This is by design: TCC stands for Tiny C Compiler.  The compiler itself is designed to be simple, so it intentionally doesn't include code to look for many kinds of optimizations.  Notice the `sub esp, 0`: this useless instruction clearly come from filling in a function-prologue template, and TCC doesn't even look for the special case where the offset is 0 bytes.  Other function need stack space for locals, or to align the stack before any child function calls, but this main() doesn't.  TCC doesn't care, and blindly emits `sub esp,0` to reserve 0 bytes.

(In fact, TCC is truly one pass, laying out machine code as it does through the C statement by statement.  It uses the `imm32` encoding for `sub` so it will have room to fill in the right number (upon reaching the end of the function) even if it turns out the function uses more than 255 bytes of stack space.  So instead of constructing a list of instructions in memory to finish assembling later, it just remembers one spot to fill in a `uint32_t`.  That's why it can't omit the sub when it turns out not to be needed.)

---

Most of the work in creating a *good* optimizing compiler that anyone will use in practice is the optimizer.  Even parsing modern C++ is peanuts compared to reliably emitting efficient asm (which not even gcc / clang / icc can do all the time, even without considering autovectorization).  Just generating working but inefficient asm is easy compared to optimizing; most of gcc's codebase is optimization, not parsing.  See Basile's answer on [Why are there so few C compilers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/273698/why-are-there-so-few-c-compilers/273711#273711)

---

The JMP (as you can see from @MichaelPetch's answer) has a similar explanation: TCC (until recently) didn't optimize the case where a function only has one return path, and doesn't need to JMP to a common epilogue.

There's even a NOP in the middle of the function.  It's obviously a waste of code bytes and decode / issue front-end bandwidth and out-of-order window size.  (Sometimes executing a NOP outside a loop or something is worth it to align the top of a loop which is branched to repeatedly, but a NOP in the middle of a basic block is basically never worth it, so that's not why TCC put it there.  And if a NOP did help, you could probably do even better by reordering instructions or choosing larger instructions to do the same thing without a NOP.  Even proper optimizing compilers like gcc/clang/icc don't try to predict this kind of subtle front-end effect.)

@MichaelPetch points out that TCC always wants its function prologue to be 10 bytes, because it's a *single-pass* compiler (and it doesn't know how much space it needs for locals until the end of the function, when it comes back and fills in the imm32).  But Windows targets need stack probes when modifying ESP / RSP by more than a whole page (4096 bytes), and the alternate prologue for that case is 10 bytes, instead of 9 for the normal one without the NOP.  So this is another tradeoff favouring compilation speed over good asm.

---

An optimizing compiler would xor-zero EAX (because that's smaller and at least as fast as `mov eax,0`), and leave out all the other instruction.  Xor-zeroing is one of the most well-known / common / basic x86 peephole optimizations, and [has several advantages other than code-size on some modern x86 microarchitectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and).

```
main:
    xor eax,eax
    ret
```

Some optimizing compilers might still make a stack frame with EBP, but tearing it down with `pop ebp` would be strictly better than `leave` on all CPUs, for this special case where ESP = EBP so the `mov esp,ebp` part of `leave` isn't needed.  `pop ebp` is still 1 byte, but it's also a single-uop instruction on modern CPUs, unlike `leave` [which is 2 or 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959890/enter-vs-push-ebp-mov-ebp-esp-sub-esp-imm-and-leave-vs-mov-esp-ebp/67424971#67424971) on modern CPUs.  (http://agner.org/optimize/, and see also other performance optimization links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.)  This is what gcc does.  It's a fairly common situation; if you push some other registers *after* making a stack frame, you have to point ESP at the right place before `pop ebx` or whatever.  (Or use `mov` to restore them.)

---

**The benchmarks TCC cares about are *compilation speed*, not quality (speed or size) of the resulting code**.  For example, [the TCC web site](https://bellard.org/tcc/) has a benchmark in lines/sec and MB/sec (of C source) vs. `gcc3.2 -O0`, where it's ~9x faster on a P4.

However, TCC is not totally braindead: [it will apparently do some inlining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737690/weird-tcc-compiler-optimization/48738740?noredirect=1#comment84478673_48738740), and as Michael's answer points out, a recent patch does leave out the JMP (but still not the useless `sub esp, 0`).

Comment: The NOP is not for alignment.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I didn't say it was.  I just said that alignment is not a plausible explanation for it being there, since the question was speculating about that as a reason.  edited to make it cleared that I don't think TCC intended it for alignment purposes either.

Comment: Yes, but you happen to mention possible uses for the NOP. There is a late addition to my answer that explains the reason why that NOP is there. TCC assumes that the function prologue is maximum 10 bytes (it doesn't know how much space is needed until after the function is parsed). There are two function prologues.One is 9 bytes, the other 10 (one is for the case where < 4096 bytes are needed and the other for >= 4096). The 9 byte version uses a NOP to pade to 10 bytes. And yes I am the upvote. Just pointing out why that NOP is there in TCC.

Comment: With Win32 PE/Win64PE when you need  >= 4096 (a page) of stack space you need to touch each stack page one at a time (in order) to prevent the stack guard pages causing a fault.

Comment: The reason for the 10 bytes is to account for the largest needed stack prologue so the space for the prologue instructions can be pre-allocated before the actual function is parsed. TCC is single pass so it doesn't know until after how much stack space is needed and which method to allocate space will be used. 10 bytes is the maximum size for function prologue  code. Any method shorter than 10 bytes is padded out with NOP. The compiler/code gen goes back after and updates the prologue with the required method.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: ah, single-pass compilation explains it.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised now at the down vote. There is reasonable info in general in this answer.