# Error thrown for ECX register when attempting to return my function

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I recently learned about local variables in MASM and I'm having some difficulty with this code:

```
gte:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8
    
    lea ecx, [ebp + 4]
    add ecx, 10
    lea edx, [ebp + 8]
    cmp ecx, edx
    jge xloop
    jmp yloop

    xloop: 
        mov eax, ecx
        jmp outloop
    yloop:
        mov eax, edx
        jmp outloop
    outloop:
        add esp, 4
        pop ebp
        ret
```

Doesn't like to return, but I am accessing the temp locations correctly and cleaning up ebp + esp in the code. I'm not sure if this helps but the address it's throwing at me is the one for ecx. Does it have to do with the compare? I've tried moving the value of ecx into a different register before comparing and I still get the same error.

Comment: `add esp, 4` does not match the `sub esp, 8`.

Comment: @Jester wow.... been staring for 20 min and did not catch that, thank you lol

Comment: `lea ecx, [ebp + 4]; add ecx, 10` is exactly the same as `lea ecx, [ebp + 14]`, which I'm pretty sure is not what you meant. And it cannot possibly ever be equal to ebp + 8. I think you want mov instead of lea.

Comment: When you're debugging, pay attention to the stack.  You can record the value of the stack pointer at the very beginning of this function (e.g. before the `push ebp`), and, then when you get to a `ret` if the stack pointer doesn't have that same value as observed earlier, things are not going to work.  You can also record the return address at the top of the stack immediately upon entry to the function (again, before the first instruction).  If that value isn't on the stack anymore b/c someone overwrote it, then things are not going to work.

Comment: Of course there are lots of other bugs your code can have.  Your clue to start paying attention to the stack the way @Erik described is when you're single-stepping and a `ret` doesn't return where you expected it to.  (Of course, as you're writing your code you always need to make sure any path of execution that reaches a `ret` reaches it with the stack pointer pointing at a return address, but sometimes you forget about that while changing around other logic.)

Comment: If you'd rather not code your stack frame size in two places, then instead of `add esp, xxx` at the end, you can `mov esp, ebp`.  (Also saves one byte of code size.) After all `ebp` contains the value that `esp` had before you adjusted it.  For that matter, the pair of instructions `mov esp, ebp / pop ebp` are equivalent to `leave` which is only one byte total, and this is the conventional way to clean up a stack frame.

Comment: (Technically `leave` is not always superior performance-wise, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959890/enter-vs-push-ebp-mov-ebp-esp-sub-esp-imm-and-leave-vs-mov-esp-ebp for gory details.)