# gcc cdecl calling convention

Tags: gcc, disassembly, cdecl

test a cdecl calling convention,but it's a little confusion about this:
original C code:

```
int __attribute__((cdecl)) add(int a,int b)
{
        int i;
        i = a+b;
        return i;
}

void __attribute__((cdecl)) print(int i, ...)
{
        int j,a,b;
        a = 2;
        b = 3;
        j = add(a,b);
}
void __attribute__((cdecl)) main(void)
{
        print(2,3);
}

void __attribute__((cdecl)) main(void)
{
        print(2,3);
}
compile code with this:
gcc test3.c -o test3 -g -mrtd
the corresponding asm like that:
(gdb) disassemble print
Dump of assembler code for function print:
   0x080483cb <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080483cc <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483ce <+3>: sub    esp,0x18
   0x080483d1 <+6>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x2
   0x080483d8 <+13>:mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],0x3
   0x080483df <+20>:mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
   0x080483e2 <+23>:mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
   0x080483e6 <+27>:mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]
   0x080483e9 <+30>:mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
   0x080483ec <+33>:call   0x80483b4 <add>
   0x080483f1 <+38>:mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
   0x080483f4 <+41>:leave  
   0x080483f5 <+42>:ret
(gdb) disassemble add
Dump of assembler code for function add:
   0x080483b4 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080483b5 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483b7 <+3>: sub    esp,0x10
   0x080483ba <+6>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x080483bd <+9>: mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x080483c0 <+12>:lea    eax,[edx+eax*1]
   0x080483c3 <+15>:mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
   0x080483c6 <+18>:mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x080483c9 <+21>:leave  
   0x080483ca <+22>:ret 
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080483f6 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080483f7 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483f9 <+3>: sub    esp,0x8
   0x080483fc <+6>: mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],0x3
   0x08048404 <+14>:mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x2
   0x0804840b <+21>:call   0x80483cb <print>
   0x08048410 <+26>:leave  
   0x08048411 <+27>:ret
```

the cdecl convention don't add some instruction like:
add esp 8 or other similar instructions after the calling function. 
why this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The code uses the [leave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474355/about-leave-in-x86-assembly) instruction, which restores the stack frame. Therefore there is no need to adjust the stack pointer separately.