# GDB ret "cannot access memory at address"

Tags: assembly, gdb, stack

Put simply:

1. top of stack `($esp) = 0xbffff49c`.
2. gdb executes `ret` instruction, which responds with `Cannot access memory at address 0x90909094`.

What reason would gdb be trying to access `0x90909094` when the value at the top of the stack is `0xbffff49c`?

Random info (in case it's needed):

```
[----------------------------------registers-----------------------------------]
EAX: 0x5a ('Z')
EBX: 0xb7fbeff4 --> 0x15ed7c 
ECX: 0xbffff428 --> 0xb7fbf4e0 --> 0xfbad2a84 
EDX: 0xb7fc0360 --> 0x0 
ESI: 0x0
EDI: 0x0 
EBP: 0x90909090 
ESP: 0xbffff49c --> 0xbffff450 --> 0xdb31c031 
EIP: 0x80485dd (<greeting+113>: ret)
EFLAGS: 0x292 (carry parity ADJUST zero SIGN trap INTERRUPT direction overflow)
[-------------------------------------code-------------------------------------]
   0x80485d0 <greeting+100>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x80487f4
   0x80485d7 <greeting+107>:    call   0x80483f0 <printf@plt>
   0x80485dc <greeting+112>:    leave  
=> 0x80485dd <greeting+113>:    ret    
   0x80485de <checkPassword>:   push   ebp
   0x80485df <checkPassword+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x80485e1 <checkPassword+3>: push   ebx
   0x80485e2 <checkPassword+4>: sub    esp,0x64
[------------------------------------stack-------------------------------------]
0000| 0xbffff49c --> 0xbffff450 --> 0xdb31c031 
0004| 0xbffff4a0 --> 0x0 
0008| 0xbffff4a4 --> 0xbffff564 --> 0xbffff6b2 ("/root/Desktop/CSCE_526/task1")
0012| 0xbffff4a8 --> 0x804876b (<__libc_csu_init+11>:   add    ebx,0x1351)
0016| 0xbffff4ac --> 0xb7fbeff4 --> 0x15ed7c 
0020| 0xbffff4b0 --> 0x8048760 (<__libc_csu_init>:  push   ebp)
0024| 0xbffff4b4 --> 0x0 
0028| 0xbffff4b8 --> 0xbffff538 --> 0x0 
[------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
gdb-peda$ n
Cannot access memory at address 0x90909094
```

I'm overflowing a buffer and trying to get it to execute some shellcode, but I'm not sure if those details are relevant considering the simplicity of the question: why is ret trying to access data not on the top of the stack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me as if your debugger isn't showing the register state after the `leave` instruction, but before it.

I believe `leave` does `esp = ebp` and that would make sense because the address it cannot access is one word after the address stored in ebp.

So I think that the problem isn't the destination of `ret` but happens when `ret` goes to access the stack to retrieve its return address.

Edit: Actually I now believe the access violation is happening inside the `leave` instruction and `ret` never executes at all. `leave` also tries to `pop ebp` and I think the access violation is there.

See some information on `leave` here: [Why does leave do "mov esp,ebp" in x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474355/about-leave-in-x86-assembly)

Comment: Yeah I changed my payload to fill EBP with a legitimate address rather than nops, and it worked in GDB. Weird behavior though, if I run it in GDB without any breaks, it works correctly; if I run it via "./prog `cat payload`" then it seg-faults. The same occurs with "./prog < payload" and "./prog `perl shellGenerate.pl`"