# Cannot access return address on x86-32

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am trying my luck with buffer overflows, however, I am stuck at one point. I overwrite the return address, so that `EIP` will point into the address of the `nop` sled of my shellcode. However, when `ret` is run, I get the error: `Cannot access memory at address 0x90909094`. Can anybody see what is wrong?

A dump from memory:

```
(gdb) x/8wx $esp
0xbffff18c: 0xbffff470  0xbffff400  0x00000000  0x08048559
0xbffff19c: 0xb7fc6ff4  0x08048550  0x00000000  0x00000000
(gdb) x/8wx 0xbffff470
0xbffff470: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
0xbffff480: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090
(gdb) nexti
Cannot access memory at address 0x90909094
(gdb) i r eip
 eip            0xbffff470  0xbffff470
```

As you can see, the return address is 0xbffff470 and on that location, my `nop` sled is placed. However, as soon as I run the next instruction (which is `ret`), I get an error. What is wrong here?
Edit: I am using x86-32

Edit: I found the answer in another post: [GDB ret "cannot access memory at address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506337/gdb-ret-cannot-access-memory-at-address) 
 Basically, the problem is right before the address esp is set to equals ebp, when in my case will be 0x90909090.. Thus, a quick solve is to not use 'A's as padding, but rather just the address in every word.

Comment: Is this x86-32? I didn't know anybody still used that! :) Tag your question [x86-32] or [x86-64] so people know which one you're using. If you're using x86-64, one bug is obvious: you should be looking at `%rip` and `%rsp`, not just `%eip` and `%esp`. Is that all it is?

Comment: Assuming that you haven't made any mistakes, is there any chance that the cpu's data execute protection is enabled and preventing instructions from being run in non-code segements?

Comment: @rcgldr I think not? If I compile with -z execstack and -fno-stack-protector it should be all good?

Comment: @Quuxplusone I am using x86-32

Comment: If the goal is to change the return address, then you could set eax to the desired return address, then after mov esp,ebp, use mov [esp],eax, ret.

Answer (score 0):

OP answers his own question (more or less):

> Edit: I found the answer in another post: [GDB ret "cannot access memory at address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506337/gdb-ret-cannot-access-memory-at-address) Basically, the problem is right before the address esp is set to equals ebp, when in my case will be 0x90909090.. Thus, a quick solve is to not use 'A's as padding, but rather just the address in every word.

In other words, the problem was that he had overwritten *some* of the current function's stack frame, but hadn't overwritten the actual point on the stack where the return address was stored.

```
// let's say his function ended with a "return 0"...
xorl %eax, %eax
// now here is where he did the "x/8wx" debugger command...
// but then the function epilogue goes and does the usual thing:
movl  %esp, %ebp
popl  %ebp
// and so here, at the actual return, %esp no longer points
// to the same bytes he saw with "x/8wx"
ret
```

[The linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506337/gdb-ret-cannot-access-memory-at-address) suggests that his debugger might have some sort of glitch with the `leave` instruction (which is equivalent to the `movl`/`popl` described above), such that the debugger was *telling* the OP that he was stopped at the `ret` instruction but really the processor hadn't executed the `leave` yet.

Equivalently, the debugger might have an aversion to breakpointing in the middle of a function prologue or epilogue, such that if you try to set a breakpoint in the middle of the epilogue, it's secretly adjusted to the beginning of the epilogue.