# and esp, 0xfffffff0

Tags: assembly, x86

I don't entirely understand the line with comment in it below. I read a few posts on SO and in the `gcc` manual and learned that it is for stack address alignment but fail to understand how it does so. The code is show below:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08048414 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x08048415 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048417 <+3>: and    esp,0xfffffff0 ; why??
   0x0804841a <+6>: sub    esp,0x10
   0x0804841d <+9>: mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048510
   0x08048424 <+16>:    call   0x8048320 <puts@plt>
   0x08048429 <+21>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048520
   0x08048430 <+28>:    call   0x8048330 <system@plt>
   0x08048435 <+33>:    leave
   0x08048436 <+34>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

The code was generated using `gcc` (version 4.6.3) on linux. Thanks.

Comment: It's alignment by brute force, the lowest 4 bits are reset so by definition it is now aligned to at least 16.

Comment: It makes the address a multiple of 16, i.e. optimised for 128 bits processors.

Comment: @harold ok. yep. the last 4 bits of ESP are AND'ed with 0000b (hence the reset). But how does that make it 2^4 bytes aligned? perhaps i should understand what alignment means first.

Comment: N-byte alignment means that the start address is at a multiple of N bytes. If N is a power of 2, it also means that all the byte addresses that store the entire value are exactly the same *except* for the lowest-order log2(N) bits. This allows simple masking techniques like in the code you posted, instead of integer modulo (remainder from division) operations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the Mac ABI require 16-byte stack alignment for x86-32?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612443/why-does-the-mac-abi-require-16-byte-stack-alignment-for-x86-32)

Comment: @MikeDeSimone your explanation along with others does add up and make sense. thanks guys.

Comment: excellent. Now, I fully understand. Thanks guys for your patience. it did take a bit of time but got there! as explained by @MikeDeSimone, this is a neat masking technique! :)

Answer (score 17):

`and esp, 0xfffffff0` does a bitwise AND between the stack pointer and a constant, and stores the result back in the stack pointer.

The constant is chosen so that its low four bits are zero. Therefore the AND operation will set these bits to zero in the result, and leave the other bits of `esp` intact. This has the effect of rounding the stack pointer down to the nearest multiple of 16.

Comment: "This has the effect of rounding the stack pointer down to the nearest multiple of 16." <- tried to understand "the effect" - still progressing. thx

Comment: excellent. Now, I fully understand. Thanks for your patience. it did take a bit of time but got there! :)

Answer (score 8):

It looks like it's part of some code to set up shop at the start of `main`.

Function start: save the base frame pointer on the stack (needed by the `leave` instruction later):

```
   0x08048414 <+0>: push   ebp
```

Now we align the stack pointer to a 16-byte bound, because the compiler (for whatever reason) wants it. This could be that it always wants 16-byte aligned frames, or that the local variables need 16-byte alignment (maybe someone used a `uint128_t` or they're using a type that uses [gcc vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)). Basically, since the result will always be less than or equal to the current stack pointer, and the stack grows downward, it's just discarding bytes until it gets to a 16-byte aligned point.

```
   0x08048415 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048417 <+3>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
```

Next we subtract 16 from the stack pointer, creating 16 bytes of local variable space:

```
   0x0804841a <+6>: sub    esp,0x10
```

`puts((const char*)0x8048510);`

```
   0x0804841d <+9>: mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048510
   0x08048424 <+16>:    call   0x8048320 <puts@plt>
```

`system((const char*)0x8048520);`

```
   0x08048429 <+21>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048520
   0x08048430 <+28>:    call   0x8048330 <system@plt>
```

Exit the function (see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474355/about-leave-in-x86-assembly) about what `leave` does):

```
   0x08048435 <+33>:    leave
   0x08048436 <+34>:    ret
```

---

Example of "discarding bytes": say esp = 0x123C at the start of `main`. The first lines of code:

```
   0x08048414 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x08048415 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
```

result in this memory map:

```
0x123C: (start of stack frame of calling function)
0x1238: (old ebp value) <-- esp, ebp
```

Then:

```
   0x08048417 <+3>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
```

forces the last 4 bits of esp to 0, which does this:

```
0x123C: (start of stack frame of calling function)
0x1238: (old ebp value) <-- ebp
0x1234: (undefined)
0x1230: (undefined) <-- esp
```

There's no way for the programmer to *rely on* a certain amount of memory being between `esp` and `ebp` *at this point;* therefore this memory is discarded and not used.

Finally, the program allocates 16 bytes of stack (local) storage:

Next we subtract 16 from the stack pointer, creating 16 bytes of local variable space:

```
   0x0804841a <+6>: sub    esp,0x10
```

giving us this map:

```
0x123C: (start of stack frame of calling function)
0x1238: (old ebp value) <-- ebp
0x1234: (undefined)
0x1230: (undefined)
0x123C: (undefined local space)
0x1238: (undefined local space)
0x1234: (undefined local space)
0x1230: (undefined local space) <-- esp
```

At this point, the program can be sure there are 16 bytes of 16-byte aligned memory being pointed to by `esp`.

Comment: wow. that's comprehensive. could you explain a little bit more about what "it's just discarding bytes until it gets to a 16-byte aligned point." means? I understand the rest of them pretty well. thx

Comment: excellent. Now, I fully understand. Thanks for your patience. it did take a bit of time but got there! :)

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: _Now we align the stack pointer to a 16-byte bound, because the compiler (for whatever reason) wants it. This could be that it always wants 16-byte aligned frames, or that the local variables need 16-byte alignment (maybe someone used a uint128_t or they're using a type that uses gcc vector extensions)._ <- it might be because of `GCC` generates SSE/SSE2 supporting code. Also, I am nowhere in main() using uint128_t type.

Answer (score 5):

i know it was posted long time ago, it might help for others down the line.

> 1) In modern processors, we know that **GCC** aligns the stack defaulting to **16-byte**   alignment.
>
> 2) **16 byte** ( 128 bit ) is because of **SSE2** instructions which have **MMX** and **XMM** registers and **XMM** registers are of **128** bit.
>
> 3) so when a function call is made, it is automatically aligned to **16 byte**, outside the function it remains to **8 byte**.
>
> 4) the logic of using **0xfffffff0** is to keep the lower 4 bit to 0 ,  this is because           of simple **Boolean math** which says that in binary , the multiples of 16 have **low 4 bit to zero**  ( why four bits?   **2^4 = 16** ).