# x86-64 GNU Assembly

Tags: gnu, x86-64, assembly

While investigating a crash, I came across the following code snippet and immediately recognized that the `mov` instruction should actually be `movq` to get the correct 64-bit register operation.

```c
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
    unsigned long rbp;
    __asm__ volatile ("mov %%rbp, %0" : "=r" (rbp));
    sp = (void **) rbp;
#else
```

Further to this, I also found documentation that claims that the `rbp` register for x86-64 is general purpose and does not contain the address of the current frame. I have also found documentation that claims that `rbp` does contain the address of the current frame. Can someone clarify?

Comment: `rbp` contains the base address if you don't use [`-fomit-frame-pointer` (or similar options)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666665/trying-to-understand-gcc-option-fomit-frame-pointer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579262/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-frame-pointer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the first part of your question (`movq` instead of `mov`), the assembler (as, in this case), will recognize that your operand is 64 bits, and will correctly use `movq`. `mov` is not a valid instruction, it's a way to tell the assembler "use the right `mov` variant depending on the operands".

Regarding the second part, it's actually both: it's a general purpose register, in the sense that it can hold any value. It is also used as a stack-frame base pointer. The '2.4 Stack operation' section of the AMD64 [Application programming](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/24592_APM_v1.pdf) manual says:

> A stack is a portion of a stack segment in memory that is used to link
>   procedures. Software  conventions typically define stacks using a
>   stack frame, which consists of two registers—a stack-frame base
>   pointer (rBP) and a stack pointer (rSP)—

Comment: No, `mov` is completely valid and is the actual opcode in Intel syntax. In AT&T syntax the suffix is also not required when the context can tell the operand size, just like in Intel syntax. ["If the suffix is not specified, and there are no memory operands for the instruction, GAS infers the operand size from the size of the destination register operand (the final operand)."](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Operation_Suffixes)