# Why is dynamic link required in function activation record? (in static scoped language)

Tags: c, programming-languages

I read that the dynamic link points to the previous activation record ( aka a "stack frame"), so it makes sense in dynamic scoped programming language. But in static scoped programming language, why the access link (which points to activation record of function in one lower nesting level) isn't enough?
And specifically in C - why access link is not needed? And why dynamic link is needed?

Comment: Provide some more context. I've never heard the term "activation record" being used together with the programming language C.

Comment: Maybe OP is talking about [THIS](http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~rth/cs/cs471/f00/ARIs.html)

Comment: Is this related to a static variable in a shared library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will use this nomenclature which is more familiar to me:

> **Activation record**: Stack frame
>
> **Dynamic link**: [saved] frame pointer

So, I interpret your question as: Why are frame pointers needed?<sup>[1]</sup>

A frame pointer is *not* required.

Some compilers (e.g. Green Hills C++, GCC with -O2) don’t usually generate one or can be asked not to generate it (MSVC, GCC).

That said, it does of course have its benefits:

- **Easy traversing of the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)**: generating a [stack trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace) is as easy as traversing a linked list where the frame pointer forms the head. Makes implementing stack traces and debuggers much easier.
- **Easier code generation**: stack variables can be referenced by indexing the frame pointer instead of the all-the-time-changing stack pointer. The stack pointer changes with each push/pop, the frame pointer stays constant within a function (between the [prologue/epilogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue))
- Should things go awry, **[stack unwinding](http://blog.reverberate.org/2013/05/deep-wizardry-stack-unwinding.html)** can be done using the frame pointer. This is how Borland’s structured exception handling (SEH) works.
- **Streamlines stack management**: Particularly implementations of [`setjmp(3)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/setjmp), [`alloca(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) and [C99-VLA](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays) may (and usually do) depend on it.

Drawbacks:

- **Register usage**: a x86 got only 8 general purpose registers. one of these would need to be dedicated fully for holding the frame pointer.
- **Overhead**: the prologue/epilogue is generated for every function.

But as you noticed, a compiler can generate perfectly fine code without having to maintain a frame pointer.

---

[1] If that's not what's meant, please elaborate.

Comment: Perhaps the dynamic link is a "display link" not a "frame pointer"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The way I understand it, a dynamic link links a function's activation record with its dynamic predecessor (i.e. the caller's activation frame). Therefore I interpreted the question as meaning: Why do we need frame pointers at all. But I am not totally sure if this is what OP has in mind. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Your question might be related to the `-fomit-frame-pointer` [optimizing option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666665/trying-to-understand-gcc-option-fomit-frame-pointer).

BTW, many people are naming *call frames* (in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) what you name *activation record*. The notion of [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation), and also of [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) and [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form)s are closely related.

A dynamic link is really only useful for [*nested*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function) functions (and perhaps [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)), and standard C does not have them. Some people speak of *display* links. Standard C don't have nested functions, so don't need any related trick (display link, trampoline, ...).

The [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler provides [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) as a *C language extension*, and implement them with dynamic links on activation records, very closely to what you are thinking about. Read also the wikipages on [man or boy test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_or_boy_test) and on [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computing%29).