# What does ebp and esp in a disassembly code mean?

Tags: assembly, malware, ida

Below posted is my code. Help me out in understanding what the below code means:

```
   push    ebp
   mov     ebp, esp
   sub     esp, 230h
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695203/behaviour-of-ebp-and-esp-in-stacks-using-function-with-parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why to use ebp in function prologue/epilogue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655553/why-to-use-ebp-in-function-prologue-epilogue)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718397/what-are-the-esp-and-the-ebp-registers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a *function prologue*.

Pushes the old base pointer onto the stack, so it can be restored later:

```
   push    ebp
```

Assigns the value of stack pointer into base pointer, then a new stack frame will be created on top of the old stack frame:

```
   mov     ebp, esp
```

Moves the stack pointer further by decreasing or increasing its value (depending on whether the stack grows down or up):

```
   sub     esp, 230h
```

Here, the`230h` immediate value is the number of bytes reserved on the stack for local use in the function.

In a similar way, the *function epilogue* reverses the actions of the prologue and returns control to the calling function.

Check this related SO question: [Function Prologue and Epilogue in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765406/function-prologue-and-epilogue-in-c)

Comment: Some compilers offer the option of not using frame pointers, which frees up ebp to be used as a generic register (it would still need to be saved).