# Assembly x86 - "leave" Instruction

Tags: c, assembly

It's said that the "leave" instruction is similar to:

```
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
```

I understand the `movl %ebp, %esp` part, and that it acts to release stored up memory (as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474355/about-leave-in-x86-assembly)).

But what is the purpose of the `popl %ebp` code?

Comment: It pops `ebp` .

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's confusing what's being asked. You specifically ask about `pop %ebp` and that has a meaning outside of `LEAVE` making this question very compound. Your question on `LEAVE` is also a definite dupe. So we need to know what exactly is the question here and to keep it atomic.

Comment: Interestingly this is almost a direct dupe of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907672/need-some-explanations-about-leave-instruction-in-assembly-language

Comment: FYI: `movl %ebp, %esp` is AT&T syntax and means esp=ebp. `movl %esp, %ebp` would be the Intel syntax equivalent.

Answer (score 106):

`LEAVE` is the counterpart to `ENTER`. The `ENTER` instruction sets up a stack frame by first pushing `EBP` onto the stack and then copies `ESP` into `EBP`, so `LEAVE` has to do the opposite, i.e. copy `EBP` to `ESP` and then restore the old `EBP` from the stack.

See the section named *PROCEDURE CALLS FOR BLOCK-STRUCTURED LANGUAGES* in [Intel's Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) Vol 1 if you want to read more about how `ENTER` and `LEAVE` work.

---

`enter n,0` is exactly equivalent to (and should be replaced with)

```
push  %ebp
mov   %esp, %ebp     # ebp = esp,  mov  ebp,esp in Intel syntax
sub   $n, %esp       # allocate space on the stack.  Omit if n=0
```

**`leave` is exactly equivalent to**

```
mov   %ebp, %esp     # esp = ebp,  mov  esp,ebp in Intel syntax
pop   %ebp
```

`enter` is very slow and compilers don't use it, but `leave` is fine.  (http://agner.org/optimize).  Compilers do use `leave` if they make a stack frame at all (at least gcc does).  But if `esp` is already equal to `ebp`, it's most efficient to just `pop ebp`.

Comment: It seems like I don't understand the concept of EBP and ESP. Could you please explain both of these terms for me?

Comment: `EBP` and `ESP` are both just 32-bit general-purpose registers. Although `ESP` has a special function, which is to act as the stack pointer, and it gets implicitly modified by certain instructions (e.g. `push`, `pop`, `call`). `EBP` by convention is typically used as a stack frame pointer within functions.

Comment: [What does ebp and esp in a dissembly code means?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26684506/what-does-ebp-and-esp-in-a-dissembly-code-means) [What are the ESP and the EBP registers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718397/what-are-the-esp-and-the-ebp-registers?rq=1)

Comment: To expand on this answer, `LEAVE` or `ENTER` are not dependent on each other. That is, you can have one without the other, but the associated ASM must be present (either using these two instructions or explicitly including equivalent instructions).

Comment: So, I'm not sure I'm understanding this right. Isn't it redundant to say leave is movl %ebp, %esp, followed by popl %ebp? Doesn't the popl instruction itself move the stack pointer to where it needs to be, without a need for the movl instruction?

Comment: No(see my answer).  The base pointer is the bottom of the stack, & the stack pointer is the top.

Comment: @LewisKelsey  That's why he put the Intel syntax in comments. The GCC ecosystem(& most similar C compiler ecosystems) use AT&T syntax(although, I think there is a `.intel` directive in recent versions).

Comment: BTW, I tested on Skylake and `leave` does cost 1 uop more (total of 3) than `mov %ebp, %esp` / `pop %ebp` (total of 2) even when used as part of a function call / ret.  The 3 uops isn't including a stack-sync uop or something.  It's still maybe worth using for code-size reasons, though, because small code size for more L1i hits is not a bad thing.  GCC uses `leave` when the stack point isn't already pointing to the right place for `pop %ebp`.

Answer (score 9):

The `popl` instruction restores the base pointer, and the `movl` instruction restores the stack pointer. The base pointer is the bottom of the stack, and the stack pointer is the top.  Before the leave instruction, the stack looks like this:

```
----Bottom of Caller's stack----
...
Caller's
Variables
...
Function Parameters
----Top of Caller's Stack/Bottom of Callee's stack----   (%ebp)
...
Callee's
Variables
...
---Bottom of Callee's stack----    (%esp)
```

After the `movl %ebp %esp`, which deallocates the callee's stack, the stack looks like this:

```
----Bottom of Caller's stack----
...
Caller's
Variables
...
Function Parameters
----Top of Caller's Stack/Bottom of Callee's stack----   (%ebp) and (%esp)
```

After the `popl %ebp`, which restores the caller's stack, the stack looks like this:

```
----Bottom of Caller's stack----    (%ebp)
...
Caller's
Variables
...
Function Parameters
----Top of Caller's Stack----   (%esp)
```

The `enter` instruction saves the bottom of the caller's stack and sets the base pointer so that the callee can allocate their stack.

Also note, that, while most C compilers allocate the stack this way(at least with optimization turn'd off), if you write an assembly language function, you can just use the same stack frame if you want to, but you have to be sure to `pop` everything off the stack that you `push` on it or else you'll jump to a junk address when you return(this is because `call <somewhere>` means `push <ret address>`[or `push %eip`], `jmp <somewhere>`, and `ret` means jump to the address on the top of the stack[or `pop %eip`].  `%eip` is the register that holds the address of the current instruction).

Comment: A code block would probably look better for your ASCII diagrams than ragged back-tick lines.  You have some HTML elements inside backticks in the last paragraph.  And BTW most C compilers don't waste instructions making stack frames at all; `-fomit-frame-pointer` has been gcc's default for years even on 32-bit x86 (with optimization enabled of course).

Comment: I didn't say it wasted instructions, just pointing out that you don't have to(a lot of C references say it's done that way).  Also, I did use <code> tags for the ASCII diagrams.

Comment: No, I mean Stack Overflow code formatting: select your block and hit control-k, or click the `{}` icon.  Re: compilers: I was commenting on your *while C compilers almost always allocate the stack this way*, that *compilers* don't do that.  And BTW, you probably shouldn't use code formatting for *`pop` everything off the stack*, because you shouldn't use the `pop` instruction just to increment `esp` by more than 4, just `add $12, %esp` or whatever.  `pop %ecx` is often good if you only need it once, though.

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you to use Stack Overflow's markdown.  It supports some HTML, but for example `&lt;` isn't processed within backticks, and might not be processed at all.  Welcome to SO :)