# Need some explanations about LEAVE instruction in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

I did not understood clearly the LEAVE function, It is a condensate of those 2 instructions:

```
MOV ESP, EBP
POP EBP
```

So `MOV ESP, EBP` moves ESP downward to the level of EBP (start of the stack).

Then `POP EBP`, moves the value pointed by ESP and affects it to EBP, and also moves ESP one step downward.

But I really don't see, how those two operations are linked to the fact of leaving a function (which is the purpose of `LEAVE`).

Can you help me clarify this please ?

Comment: The purpose of `LEAVE` is just to undo what `ENTER` did, i.e. to "free" a stack frame created by `ENTER`.

Comment: so, it's to remove the current stack frame, and point to the one below ?

Comment: It balances what the ENTER instruction does.  Setting up a stack frame and tearing it down again.  You need to forget that these instructions exist, they only made sense 20+ years ago when processors were not super-scalar yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["enter" vs "push ebp; mov ebp, esp; sub esp, imm" and "leave" vs "mov esp, ebp; pop ebp"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959890/enter-vs-push-ebp-mov-ebp-esp-sub-esp-imm-and-leave-vs-mov-esp-ebp)

Answer (score 9):

A common prologue, sequence of instructions at the start of a routine, in the 32-bit and 16-bit eras was

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

sub esp, <local_var_size>

push <clobbered_reg1>
push <clobbered_reg2>
...
```

Nothing is casual here, the order of the instruction is important, we end up with

```
|parN | <-- EBP + 04 + n*4                 par1..parN = Routine parameters
...     ...                                ra = Return address
|par2 | <-- EBP + 0ch                      o ebp = Original (caller) EBP
|par1 | <-- EBP + 08h                      lvar1..lavarM = Local variables
|ra   | <-- EBP + 04h                      creg1..cregK = Clobbered registers
|o ebp| <-- EBP
|lvar1| <-- EBP - 04h
|lvar2| <-- EBP - 08h
...    ...
|lvarM| <-- EBP - m*4
|creg1|
|creg2|
...
|cregK| <-- ESP
```

Look how all the data is easily accessed with a suitable pointer from `ebp` (parameters as successive positive offsets greater or equal to 8, local vars as negative offsets lower or equal to 4) and how well this model scales for a greater number of local vars or parameters.
For this reason `ebp` is called the frame pointer.

The epilogue must undo all of this.
One possible variant is

```
pop <clobbered_regK>
...
pop <clobbered_reg1>

add esp, <local_var_size>

pop ebp
ret n*4
```

However this involves repeating `<local_var_size>` - it is easy to forget to keep both versions in sync.
We can take advantage of the fact that `ebp` is the value of `esp` before the allocation of the local vars, thus by restoring that value we effectively deallocate them all.

```
pop <clobbered_regK>
...
pop <clobbered_reg1>

mov esp, ebp

pop ebp
ret n*4
```

But the third and second instruction from the end are what the `leave` instruction does. So:

```
pop <clobbered_regK>
...
pop <clobbered_reg1>

leave
ret n*4
```

is the equivalent prologue.

---

[`enter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959890/enter-vs-push-ebp-mov-ebp-esp-sub-esp-imm-and-leave-vs-mov-esp-ebp) is a very slow instruction (https://agner.org/optimize) so compilers never use it, but `leave` can be used for optimizing code space with only a tiny impact on performance (which may be balanced out by the code-size saving).  GCC uses `leave` when a `pop ebp` on its own wouldn't be sufficient, with most `-mtune=` settings.

On current Intel CPUs (Skylake for example), `leave` costs 3 total uops, vs. 2 for `mov esp, ebp` / `pop ebp`.  In a real test-case accounting for possible differences in stack-sync uops by calling (from a repeat loop) an actual tiny function that sets up EBP as a frame pointer and allocates some stack space, then tears it down, HW performance counters measured the leave function as taking 1 more front-end uop per call than the mov/pop function.  But the leave function ran slightly faster for some unknown reason, even with both aligned by 32.  (@petercordes ran this test.)

Answer (score 2):

> But I really don't see, how those two operations are linked to the fact of leaving a function (which is the purpose of LEAVE).

That's not `LEAVE`'s purpose. That the purpose of `RET`. Leave doesn't actually do anything *except* modify the stack. In fact you can `LEAVE` and then set up another stack frame and still remain in the same function.

Comment: _LEAVE_ doesn't just adjust the stack it also restores the previous value of _RBP/EBP/BP_  that was pushed on the stack.