# How to get a variable that stored in the stack?

Tags: variables, memory, operating-system, stack

While programming (for example, in C), a lot of variables are kept in the stack.
A stack is a FIFO data structure, and we can pop only the top value of the stack.

let's say I have 100 variables stored in the stack, and I want to get the value of the one of them, which is not in the top of the stack.
How do I get it? Do the operating system pop all the variables which are newer in the stack until getting the wanted variable, then push all of them back inside?
Or is there a different way the operating system can approach a variable inside the stack?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do it? There is probably another, better solution to your problem.

Comment: It's LIFO, in C, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The* stack, as used in languages like C, is not a typical LIFO. It's called a stack because it is used in a way *similar* to a LIFO: When a procedure is called, a new frame is pushed onto the stack. The frame typically contains local variables and bookkeeping information like where to return to. Similarly, when a procedure returns, its frame is popped off the stack.

There's nothing magical about this. The compiler (not the operating system) allocates a register to be used as a *[stack pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#The_stack_and_frame_pointers)* - let's call it `SP`. By convention, `SP` points to the memory location of the next free stack word:

```
+----------------+ (high address)
|   argument 0   |
+----------------+
|   argument 1   |
+----------------+
| return address |
+----------------+
|    local 0     |
+----------------+
|    local 1     |
+----------------+                  +----+    
|    free slot   |  <-------------- | SP |
+----------------+ (low address)    +----+
```

To push a value onto the stack, we do something like this (in pseudo-assembly):

```
STORE [SP], 42 ; store the value 42 at the address where SP points
SUB SP, 1      ; move down (the stack grows down!) to the next stack location
```

Where the notation `[SP]` is read as "the contents of the memory cell to which `SP` points". Some architectures, notably x86, provide a `push` instruction that does both the storing and subtraction. To pop (and discard) the *n* top values on the stack, we just add *n* to `SP`*.

Now, suppose we want to access the `local 0` field above. Easy enough if our CPU has a [base+offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Base_plus_offset.2C_and_variations) addressing mode! Assume `SP` points to the free slot as in the picture above.

```
 LOAD R0, [SP+2] ; load "local 0" into register R0
```

Notice how we *didn't* need to pop `local 0` off the stack first, because we can reference any field using its offset from the stack pointer.

Depending on the compiler and machine architecture, there may be another register pointing to the area between locals and arguments (or thereabouts). This register, typically called a [frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579262/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-frame-pointer), remains fixed as the stack pointer moves around.

I want to stress the fact that normally, the operating system isn't involved in stack manipulation at all. The kernel allocates the initial stack, and possibly monitors its growth, but leaves the pushing and popping of values to the user program.

*For simplicity, I've assumed that the machine word size is 1 byte, which is why we subtract 1 from SP. On a 32-bit machine, pushing a word onto the stack means subtracting (at least) four bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I. The operating system doesn't do anything directly with your variables.

II. Don't think of the stack as a physical stack (the reason for this is overly simple: it isn't one). The elements of the stack can be accessed directly, and the compiler generates code that does so. Google "stack pointer relative addressing".