# Lua 5.2 compiled with MINGW32 crashes my host program when a Lua error occurs

Tags: c, lua, mingw32

Compiling Lua 5.2 using MINGW32 creates a library (lua52.dll) that may crash the host application when a Lua error occurs.

I detected this bug by making a Lua syntax error in a test script. If the script had no errors at all, the host program ran it successfully. However, when loading an invalid script (e.g. with a missing THEN in an IF block) the host program crashed.

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
//Load the script    
int status = luaL_loadfile(L, "foo.lua");
if (status == 0) {
    //Run the script
    ....
} else {
    warn("LUA script error: %d. %s", status, lua_tostring(L, -1));       
    lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

If the script has no syntax errors, `status`is 0 and the script is successfully executed. Otherwise, `luaL_loadfile` does not return and the program crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the `CFLAGS` specified in the Lua's Makefile. Originally, `src/Makefile` contains the following line:

```
CFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -DLUA_COMPAT_ALL $(SYSCFLAGS) $(MYCFLAGS)
```

The problem is fixed by changing it to:

```
CFLAGS= -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -DLUA_COMPAT_ALL $(SYSCFLAGS) $(MYCFLAGS)
```

**EXPLANATION**

Lua's error handling is based on the use of functions `setjmp` and `longjmp`. The `-O2` optimization flag implicitly makes the compiler to [omit the frame pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579262/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-frame-pointer). To avoid this, we pass `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to override this setting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has been reported before: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-10/msg00549.html. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh, glad I end up with the same solution! I've been unable to find this issue by googling so I decided to post this message in StackOverflow. Thank you anyway!