# How does `gdb` compute the bounds of a stack frame?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, x86-64, stack-frame

I am debugging a new thread library, in which I set the stack register `rsp` manually (to switch to a user-managed stack), and then invoke a function which never returns.

When I try to get a backtrace in gdb, I get the following output.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  load (_m=std::memory_order_seq_cst, this=<error reading variable: Asked for position 0 of stack, stack only has 0 elements on it.>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.9/atomic:209
#1  Arachne::schedulerMainLoop () at Arachne.cc:236
#2  0x000000000040268d in Arachne::threadMainFunction (id=<optimized out>) at Arachne.cc:135
#3  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

How does `gdb` determine that the stack has 0 elements in it?

More generally, how does `gdb` determine how many elements the stack has?

Comment: [frame pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers)

Comment: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/Internals%20Stack-Frames could be helpful

Comment: it may differ if you have 32 bit or 64 bit

Comment: On x86-64 Linux, backtracing / exception-handling stack unwinding relies on metadata in the `.eh_frame_hdr` section.  Frame pointers are completely optional, and may not be used even if code is compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091231/what-do-the-eh-frame-and-eh-frame-hdr-sections-store-exactly and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055891/implementing-stack-backtrace-without-using-ebp.  Please have a look at those and see if either this is a dup of either.  There were more search hits for `.eh_frame_hdr`.

Comment: Sorry I'm being lazy and not taking the time to figure out which one is the best dup target myself, but I've never had to dig into the details myself.  I just know that there is metadata generated by the compiler.  I should probably look up how to generate the same metadata for hand-written asm functions sometime, though.  Anyway, hopefully this clue is enough for you to be able to find the answer yourself.  IDK how gdb figures out that it's reached the end of the unwinding.  But maybe when it looks for another return address to index the metadata, and it finds something bogus.

Answer (score 1):

`Asked for position 0 of stack, stack only has 0 elements on it.` comes from [gdb/dwarf2/expr.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/dwarf2/expr.c;h=9986258333667b178c6afa2ba91eb661b6f48e6e;hb=HEAD) and doesn't refer to your CPU stack. Instead, it complains about the stack that [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) expressions work on.

This might mean that your DWARF debug info is invalid. Or what you did with `esp` confused GDB's DWARF expression evaluator.