# Why does gcc create a new stack for each function?

Tags: c

I have been looking at disassembled c recently (all compiled with gcc). I noticed every function begins with

```
push rbp 
mov rbp, rsp
```

And ends with

```
pop rbp
```

Or the equivalent registers. I’ve heard this referee to as setting up a new stack for the function, but how does this actually benefit the code. Wouldn’t the code work exactly the same without it, as rbp can’t be accessed or chanced in c (without inline assembly) and pointers and variables are all offsets from `rsp`

Comment: How does it benefit the code? It doesn't. That's why gcc  only does it if you don't turn optimization on.

Comment: new stack FRAME for the function.

Comment: Did you compile it without optimizations? If that is true the compiler tries to represent the code exactly the way you typed it in C.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41912684/1971013) help?

Comment: @PSkocik but if it has no benefit, it’s just extra instructions, so why would it ever need to be there

Comment: Debuggability, that's why.

Comment: @meaning-matters I swear I did google it, but maybe I’m just bad at formulating questions

Comment: @BElgy Take  a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666665/trying-to-understand-gcc-option-fomit-frame-pointer or the gcc documentation ofthe `-fomit-frame-pointer` option. It looks like the answers is something along the lines: debuggers, weird machines, and histerical reasons.

Comment: I searched for "rbp register" and the above link was the top result.

Comment: I think [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666665/trying-to-understand-gcc-option-fomit-frame-pointer#comment20499949_14666730) in @PSkocik 's reference is the best answer to when is a a new frame needed. There are only a few possibilities to make a function complex enough that a real benefit in the ease of compilation and code generated is preferred to performance. It doesn't answer this question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the execution of the function, the stack pointer may vary as it is used for temporary storage during calculations. You must however still be able to access the function parameters, which are offsets from the base pointer (rbp).