# What is the "-4" for in assembler: movl $1, -4(%rbp)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, addressing-mode

```
int x=1;
int y=2;
int z=3;
```

turns into

```
movl    $1, -4(%rbp)
movl    $2, -8(%rbp)
movl    $3, -12(%rbp)
```

What is the -4,-8,-12 for ?
Why is it going by 4's?
4 bytes = 32 bits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-4 / -8 / -12 bytes relative to the address held in `rbp`, which is the [pointer to the top of the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912684/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-rbp-register-in-x86-64-assembler) (which grows downward). 4 bytes / 32 bits because that is the size of `int` on your machine.