# NASM push before ret

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

When a `call` happens, it is my understanding that the address of the caller is pushed onto the stack, and when a `ret` is executed, it jumps to the popped value from the stack.

What happens if I push a value and forget to pop it? Wouldn't `ret` simply `pop` what it expects to be the return address from the stack and be sorely mistaken by whatever value was actually at the top of the stack? E.g:

```
Function:
    mov ax, "A"
    push ax
    ret

call Function
```

Additionally, I wonder the same thing about `pusha` and `popa`. If I `push` a value after a `pusha` does the `popa` now use that value when it pops however many registers it uses, leaving the original first register on the stack and restoring every register to the register + 1's value?

Comment: It's exactly as you say. Note you can try such things in a debugger.

Comment: You're exactly right.  FYI, that's why calling conventions typically use both a "stack pointer" (e.g. "esp") *AND* a [frame pointer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194339/frame-pointer-explanation) (e.g. "ebp").  You can read more here: [What is the purpose of the EBP frame pointer register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579262/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-ebp-frame-pointer-register)

Answer (score 3):

Stack is just a memory, it is not "typed" anyhow, you can always push one register and pop another.

`ret` is just a `pop` into the `ip` register so push/ret is an inefficient way to `jmp`.  There's no magic that matches up with the previous `call`.

You can even change data on stack without using push, just change it using `esp` or `ebp` pointer. And sure you can accidentally overwrite return address. And causing your program to accidentally overwrite return address is a well known technique used by malware.